# Html input number is not getting numeric keyboard input

Tags: html, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

Here is the `input` type `number`

```html
<input type="Number" id="yPos" />
```

it is working fine and i am able to change it through mouse

[image]

But it is not getting numeric input from keyboard. How can i enable it?

Edit:
I found that UnitywebGL is creating this problem otherwise the keyboard input is working correctly in html controls.

Comment: Look at your keyboard's Num Lock, if its on or off? Or change type="number" instead of Number.

Comment: Click on tab button and go to input section after that use up and down arrow key, number will increase and decrease.

Comment: no matter it is on/off it is not getting input

Comment: It is already working fine as you want, could it be another problem? Can you share browser info?

Comment: change type="number" (all leter in lowercase) instead of "Number" and check.

Comment: check correctly it get the value.May be your browser fault

Comment: It's working fine..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no issue with the html input field. It was related to the unity webgl:

> Keyboard input and focus handling. By default, Unity WebGL will
>   process all keyboard input send to the page, regardless of whether the
>   WebGL canvas has focus or not. This is done so that a user can start
>   playing a keyboard-based game right away without the need to click on
>   the canvas to focus it first ([source](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-input.html)).

So the Unity canvas was consuming my all keyboard input. No matter I tried to enter/select my input control, it will not get input from keyboard. So I used

```
WebGLInput.captureAllKeyboardInput
```

to activate/deactive unity canvas input based on user selection.

Answer (score -1):

First, correct the form. The type should be "number" without caps, i.e:

```
type="number"
```

Also check if you have turned off the num lock.